# React: How to use this API?

Tags: reactjs, api, frontend, backend

First of all, I am new into using APIs'.

I want to use the IMDB unofficial API (https://english.api.rakuten.net/hmerritt/api/imdb-internet-movie-database-unofficial/endpoint). I am aware of the fact that to make an API request, I need to write the url of the  backend in axios.get('url). In the case of the mentioned API, what address should I put inside axios.get? How can I make an API get/request with this above mentioned API? Please help.

Comment: Did you read the detail section? It specifies which url you go for certain query

Comment: @kunquan I want to know which base address to use? Like xyz.com/(API details). what is xyz in this case?